# Maven: project setup

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

I am starting a new project as well as starting with Maven.
I am not sure my project-structure with Maven is decent and so I would like to ask. I describe the project with a little example.

The projects name should be MyPrj.

It consists of 3 parts (server, client, lib).

Server and client are programs (main) and lib does include helper-classes both will use (e.g. for logging).

I designed 3 maven-projects - 1 per part.

```
MyPrj/
  client/
     pom.xml, src, target, ...
  server/
     pom.xml, src, target, ...
  lib/
     pom.xml, src, target
```

The parts java package-names are

```
MyPrj.client
MyPrj.server
MyPrj.lib
```

The maven addressing is

```
groupId: MyPrj, artifactId: client, version: 0.1
groupId: MyPrj, artifactId: server, version: 0.1
groupId: MyPrj, artifactId: lib, version: 0.1
```

In them POM of client and server is a dependency to lib.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>MyPrj</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Is that setup ok or not typical for a maven project?

Answer (score 2):

Your Maven project looks good but you missed one thing : **the parent**.

Your `MyPrj` project should have its own `pom.xml`.

```
MyPrj/
  pom.xml
  client/
     pom.xml, src, target, ...
  server/
     pom.xml, src, target, ...
  lib/
     pom.xml, src, target
```

In the pom.xml of `MyPrj`, you can declare the **submodules** of your Maven project as following :

```
<project>
  ...

  <modules>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>lib</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

The parent of multi-module Maven project has a lot of interesting features (dependencies management, repositories, SCM management, ...).

I suggest you to take a look to the following documentation :

- [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)